# Easiest way to export surveymonkey results

Tags: surveymonkey

I'm looking at the simplest way to get surveymonkey results without logging into SM and manually exporting them.  I see they have an API.  I'm assuming that we would need to create a program that can utilize a REST webservice to return the survey results?

Are there any 3 party vendors who have already created something to do this so we don't need to reinvent the wheel?  If not, what would be the easiest way to go about this, since I have limited access to programmers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about third party vendors at the moment that have already created an export tool, but you can export your responses with the api.

If you're pulling out responses you're probably looking for the [bulk endpoint](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk).

You can see examples in the docs, but you would just have to do a GET request to that endpoint, an example cURL looks like this:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: bearer <your_access_token>" -H "https://api.surveymonkey.net/v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/bulk?api_key=<your_api_key>"
```

You can also click the `Run in Postman` button to open an API tool to test with.

For those looking for third-party tools, you can follow [our partners page](https://www.surveymonkey.com/integrations/) to follow new apps and integrations that are available and partnered with SurveyMonkey. You can also search SurveyMonkey on [github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=surveymonkey) there are many developers who publish SDKs and other tools to make using the API easier.